# Express NodeJS Selenium - Video Recording the remote browser activity

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, video-streaming, video-recording

I am working on NodeJS Selenium tool and executing the test cases on a remote machine over HTTP. I am capturing screenshots of the web page at every specified point, so that the user an see what happened in each page.

But for improved user experience, I wanted to record the video of what is happening in remote machine (like opening the browser, entering text inputs, clicking on buttons etc.)

I am using **screen-capture-recorder** package to record the video. Which is working fine if I execute locally. When I execute the same thing on remote machine via HTTP, it is not able to record the video. I guess this is because the session is not interactive to record the video. Means it doesn't find GUI to record.

Are there any other solutions to achieve this?